# Are there any digital walkie talkies or radios with CPUs on them?

Tags: rf, cpu

That's it! Are there any modern radios (not ***smartphones***. More like walkie talkies or ham sets or those used in cars) that contain CPUs on them and somehow interact with the analog radio signals?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131564/discussion-on-question-by-4d4143-are-there-any-digital-walkie-talkies-or-radios).

Comment: @VoltageSpike I'm allowing myself to re-surface the link to the "causing" question over at infosec: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/257248/can-modern-radios-ham-sets-digital-walkie-talkies-be-exploited?noredirect=1#comment530018_257248

Answer (score 4, accepted):

25-years ago, Motorola has made little walk-in-talkies that could be paired with another similar unit so you could avoid hearing other over the air traffic and others could not hear your traffic. Their claim was some type of encryption and signal processing so, I can't imagine anything was done without a microcontroller.

They are still available...
https://www.motorolasolutions.com/en_us/products/two-way-radios/consumer-two-way-radios.html

Comment: seriously, **any** radio you can buy that has more than a single button will contain a CPU of sorts.

Comment: Yeah, by starting my comment with, "25-years-ago" was meant to imply that this is ancient technology history so, I'm quite sure every 2-way OTA system will have some Type of microcontroller by now.